# oil rig scammers

Tags: scams, money-transfer

I have been talking to a man on hangouts for a couple months who says he is a private contractor and working on a rig in Germany now and says he needs money to pay taxes before he can work with cranes, but used all his money to purchase equipment for the job. Is this possibly legit?

Comment: No. This is a scam.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about a personal finance related scam, just a scam in general.

Comment: How could this *not* be a scam? I personally do not make a habit of sending my hard-earned money to strangers on the internet.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like a typical [romance scam](https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/what-you-need-know-about-romance-scams).

1. Create a fake identity which gives you a plausible reason why you are unable to meet the mark in person
2. Build a personal connection to people online
3. Make up a more or less convincing story about why you are in urgent need for money
4. Ask the mark for money
5. Take the money
6. See if you can convince the mark to give you even more money by claiming it never arrived, escalating the story ("They wanted $3000 but now I got another bill and I actually need $6000 - please send more!") or making up a new one.
7. When the mark won't send any more money, break contact and find another one

"Oil rig worker" is indeed one of their standard cover stories (others are "soldier on assignment" and "doctor on humanitarian mission in developing country").

While it is not entirely implausible that you indeed met a real oil rig worker working on a German rig (they exist in the North Sea, but no longer in the Baltic Sea) and that they are indeed in financial difficulties (it happens), ask yourself why they ask *you* instead of first exceeding all the other options which should be available to them:

- Ask the tax bureau for an extension or installment plan for their tax debt (which they often grant)
- Ask friends and family they have actually met in real life
- Ask their bank for a loan
- Ask their employer for a loan
- Ask their colleagues for a loan

And there is no reason why having tax debt would forbid them from operating cranes. That part of their story makes absolutely no sense.

By the way, when these scammers come up with their cover stories, they often add a detail which is easy to prove wrong with a cursory online search. This is intentional to weed out those marks who will do research and only spend time on those who don't. So you might want to fact-check a couple things they told you in the beginning of your relationship. Does the oil rig they claim to work on exist? Is it operated by the company they claim to work for (does that company even exist)? Does their description of the oil rig and life circumstances on it match reality? Does the geography of locations match? (a common intentional mistake is to claim to be in [location] in [country] when [location] is actually in a different country)